# putting a node within a node

Tags: java, xml, nodes

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
<EMOTable1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.europe.eu/tad.xsd">
  <RED>
    <ALE>B00009</ALE>
  </RED>
```

I have so far written the following but im failing to put the ALE within RED, with the value B00009

I have so far got the following:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = document.createElement("EMOTable1");


    rootElement.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    rootElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.europe.eu/tad.xsd");
    document.appendChild(rootElement);//append the root element to the doc

    Element REI = document.createElement("RED");//create a new element
        rootElement.appendChild(REI);//append this new element called REI
        Node node = document.createElement("B00009");
```

REI.appendChild(node);//put the contents within the new element

Comment: I don't see where you create your Element ALE, you  should create this one.  You add your element ALE as child of REI element. Finally, you add your node to the element ALE.

Comment: Also note that your XML uses namespaces, so you should use a namespace aware document builder and use `createElementNS` to create your elements in that target namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is missing the creation of your element `ALE`.

So, You should create this element that contains the text `B00009` and add as child of your element `REI`:

EX:

```
Element ALE = document.createElement("ALE");
Text codeALE = document.createTextNode("B00009");
ALE.appendChild(codeALE);
REI.appendChield(ALE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example - i was trying to create a new node which was all wrong. This has helped at lot